# Probability-based optimal Test Scheduling

Tags: optimization, probability

Consider the cases where the test process will be terminated as soon as a defect is detected. We need to consider probability of passing in order to schedule the test sets so that the expected total test time will be minimized.

Ex:

```
91  0.805414173
79  0.73921812
61  0.940068379
```

Expected time :  `t1(1-p1) + (t1+t2)p1(1-p2) + ...`

Can you please help in the algorithm to order the tests such that it will return minimum expected time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tasks can be ordered by

```
t1/(1-p1)
```

This will give the minimum test time.